# How can I save log file whose name is logger name in log4net?

Tags: log4net

In log4net we can use `ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(something));` to create logger.

But I want to save log with the name of "something" in `GetLogger()` method. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the name of the log file?

Comment: no,I want to save log by class name

Comment: So long as the class you want to use implements ILog it should work. What is the actual problem you get?

Comment: that is not key.I want to save log file by the class name called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log4net does not support this by configuration. If you have only a few classes then you can configure an appender per class but depending on the number of classes your configuration file will get quite big.

You could of course write your own appender with that functionality but you may want to consider to do log to a database instead. This way you can filter your log messages in any way you see fit.

---

Edit: 
You could also create the appenders programmatically per logger. But I would not go for it...