# Write to file name based on logger

Tags: log4net

I want to write to a file name that is named after the logger I create.

For example if I call LogManager.GetLogger("MyClass") then I want it to log to MyClass.log.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I save log file whose name is logger name in log4net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742071/how-can-i-save-log-file-whose-name-is-logger-name-in-log4net)

Comment: Thanks @samy. Looks like I have to create loggers/appenders programmatically to really get the functionality I want.